# how to group all users in a product list if they have the same product?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a function who get a array like this:

```
$userData[] = [
    'userAddress' => $user->getAdress,
    'userEmail' => $user->getEmail(),
    'userPhone' => $user->getPhone(),
    'userFirstname' => $user->getFirstName(),
    'productCode' => $market->getProduct()->getCode(),
];

if ($currentProduct !== $market->getProductCode() or $currentProduct === 0) {
    $marketProduct = $answer->getProduct();
    $productData[] = [
        'productCode' => $marketProduct->getCode(),
        'productModel' => $marketProduct->getModel(),
        'productCollection' => $marketProduct->getCollection(),
        'productBrand' => $marketProduct->getBrand(),
        'productFirstOnlineDate' => $answerProduct->getFirstOnlineDate(),
        'usersData' => $userData,
    ];
}
```

and this fuction i call it in a foreach from a other fuction like that:

```
$productData = [];

foreach ($datas as $item) {

    ...
    ...
    $productData[] = $this->getAlertReportData($currentProduct);

    ...
}
```

and when i do a dump `alertData` out of the foreach i have a result like that for exemple

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "productCode" => 555
    "productModel" => "productModel"
    "usersData" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "userAddress" => "111 ... paris"
        "userEmail" => "lala@gmail.com"
        "productCode" => 555
      ]
    ]
  ],
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "productCode" => 555
    "productModel" => "productModel"
    "usersData" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "userAddress" => "222 ... nice"
        "userEmail" => "lolo@gmail.com"
        "productCode" => 555
      ]
    ]
  ],
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "productCode" => 123
    "productModel" => "productModel"
    "usersData" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "userAddress" => "123 ... monaco"
        "userEmail" => "mona@gmail.com"
        "productCode" => 123
      ]
    ]
  ],
]
```

and i have a problem, I want to group all the users together in the production list if they have the same product. exemple :

```
array:5 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "productCode" => 555
        "productModel" => "productModel"
        "usersData" => array:2 [▼
          0 => array:3 [▼
            "userAddress" => "111 ... paris"
            "userEmail" => "lala@gmail.com"
            "productCode" => 555
          ],
          1 => array:3 [▼
            "userAddress" => "222 ... nice"
            "userEmail" => "lolo@gmail.com"
            "productCode" => 555
          ]
        ]
      ],
      2 => array:3 [▼
        "productCode" => 123
        "productModel" => "productModel"
        "usersData" => array:1 [▼
          0 => array:3 [▼
            "userAddress" => "123 ... monaco"
            "userEmail" => "mona@gmail.com"
            "productCode" => 123
          ]
        ]
      ],
    ]
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you,

```
function unique_array($my_array, $key) { 
    $result = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
    $key_array = array(); 
    
    foreach($my_array as $val) { 
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
            $result[$i] = $val; 
        } 
        $i++; 
    } 
    return $result; 
}  


$getAllProducts = array([
        'productCode' => 111,
        'productModel' => 'productModel 1',
        'productCollection' => 'productCollection 1',
        'productBrand' => 'productBrand 1',
        'productFirstOnlineDate' => '2020'],
               
        ['productCode' => 222,
        'productModel' => 'productModel 2',
        'productCollection' => 'productCollection 2',
        'productBrand' => 'productBran 2',
        'productFirstOnlineDate' => '2020'],

        ['productCode' => 111,
        'productModel' => 'productModel 3',
        'productCollection' => 'productCollection 3',
        'productBrand' => 'productBran 3',
        'productFirstOnlineDate' => '2020'],

        ['productCode' => 444,
        'productModel' => 'productModel 4',
        'productCollection' => 'productCollection 4',
        'productBrand' => 'productBran 4',
        'productFirstOnlineDate' => '2020'],

        ['productCode' => 555,
        'productModel' => 'productModel 5',
        'productCollection' => 'productCollection 5',
        'productBrand' => 'productBran 5',
        'productFirstOnlineDate' => '2020'],
);

$getAllProduct = unique_array($getAllProducts,'productCode');

foreach($getAllProduct as  &$row ){
    $Current_Code = $row['productCode'];
    $getUsers = getUsers($Current_Code);
    $row['userData'] = $getUsers;
}

function getUsers($Current_Code){
    $userData = array([
        'userAddress' => "111 ... paris",
        'userEmail' => "lala@gmail.com",
        'productCode' => 111 ],
        [
            'userAddress' => "222 ... paris",
            'userEmail' => "lala@gmail.com",
            'productCode' => 222],
        [
            'userAddress' => "222 ... paris",
            'userEmail' => "lala@gmail.com",
            'productCode' => 222],
        [
            'userAddress' => "333 ... paris",
            'userEmail' => "lala@gmail.com",
            'productCode' => 333],
        [
            'userAddress' => "333 ... paris",
            'userEmail' => "lala@gmail.com",
            'productCode' => 333],
        [
            'userAddress' => "444 ... paris",
            'userEmail' => "lala@gmail.com",
            'productCode' => 444],
        [
            'userAddress' => "555 ... paris",
            'userEmail' => "lala@gmail.com",
            'productCode' => 555]
        );

    foreach($userData as  $key => $row){        
        if ( $row['productCode'] != $Current_Code  ) {
             unset($userData[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $userData;
}
print_r($getAllProduct);
```

Comment: Thank for you help, I don’t realy know if it’s what I need, I think you group soles users together and me I want to group in the productData all the users who got his product code. (Sorry my English is medium)